# Microsoft Family Tree in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Do we have any provision to create the Graphical structure in C#. Like as show in the figure below? IN .NET (3.5 or 4.0 or 4.5)

I meant, when click on a button, a Square box comes on the screen. When you have already selected a Square Box, and click the Button, this connects new square Box with existing one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Family.Show`](http://familyshow.codeplex.com/) open source `WPF` project on `CodePlex`. It has both the executable and source code which you can use as a reference. It demonstrates display of Tree like Family hierarchy structures using WPF and customized appearances for the family tree using `Data Templates` and other features.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Special Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Closet thing is the `TreeView` control in WinForms and WPF - but painting your own controls is fun! `System.Drawing` - knock yourself out :)